# How to mimic submit button from custom modal form

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

I have a form to show the grid data (index.php) and a custom modal form (frmbts.php) to edit the data from the grid. I dont know how to submit/post the data from the modal form then close the modal form after submit like jqgrid's form add/edit. I can submit the data if i placed the submit button in frmbts.php. but that not i want to achieve (i cannot close the modal form after submit).

here is the the grid's code (index.php)

```
   jQuery(document).ready(function(){ ...
      jQuery("#list").jqGrid('navGrid','#page',{edit:true,add:true,del:true,search:true,refresh:true,position:'right',
            editfunc: function(id){ 
                jQuery('#frmbts').load('frmbts.php?id='+id);
                jQuery('#frmbts').dialog({width:670,height:550,modal:true,title:'Edit Data',
                buttons: { "Cancel": function() {
                    jQuery(this).dialog("close"); 
                }, "Save": function() { <-- i want use this to submit data
                    //code to submit the form then close the form
                    jQuery(this).dialog("close"); 
                } },
                });
            }}, ...
    <div id="content">
        <form id="frm" method="post" action="csvExport.php">
            <div id="frmbts"></div>
            <table id="list"></table>
            <div id="page"></div>
            <input id="csvBuffer" name="csvBuffer" type="hidden" value="">
            <input id="typeinfo" name="typeinfo" type="hidden" value="">
        </form>
    </div>
```

modal form code (frmbts.php)

```
<?php

    $id = $_REQUEST['id'];

    if(isset($_POST['submit']))
    {
    //update data
    }
?>

<form name="frmsubmit" method="post" action="frmbts.php">
    <table>...</table>
    <input type="button" name="cancel" value="cancel">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <input type="submit" name="save" id="save" value="Save"> <--- just test. not the way i want 
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so you want to submit the form but stay at the same page, without a page reload, and close the modal div. You need to use ajax for this.

First of all, change all name's to id's in your form, then change your submit button for a normal button and use this:

```
$.post('frmbts.php', {
    cancel: $('#cancel').value(),
    save: $('#save').value()
}, function(response) {
    // close your modal div here.
});
```

What i don't understand is how you show your form because i see that it's defined inside frmbts.php, so doing this that way is a bit strange. Think of using a new php to ONLY process the POST data and learn a bit of what [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) and [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29) mean, jQuery have a lot of functions for this and it's so easy and powerful.

So, the correct implementation for this is to put your POST processing code inside a new PHP and make that PHP to echo some JSON response, so your $.post call can receive a JSON response with data about if the process was successful, or any other data you want to get in response to your post. Also take a look at what [MVC](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller) is.

Comment: Hi Sergi Ramon, thank you. it work. but after submit the modal form dont close. even the page redirect to frmbts.php. how to close the modal form without redirect to frmbts after submit? i have placed jQuery(this).dialog("close") but it dont work.

Comment: That's a totally different solution, you need to use ajax for this, i will change the answer.

Comment: sorry for my confusing. actually i want to say the modal form do close after submit but the index.php redirect to frmbts.php that i dont want to.

Comment: You need to do this the way I say in the new answer. A submit of a form always redirect the browser so if you don't want it to redirect you can't use submit, you need to do some kind of background communication, that's called AJAX.

Comment: You can put your modal form inside an `<iframe>` too, it's an easier solution but a bit more dirty. Just load your frmbts.php inside an `<iframe>`.

Answer (score 0):

Right so you're loading the from frmbts.php into your modal popup window? I would give the submit input something in jQuery to check if its clicked, and instead call something similar as below. Note I've given your new form the ID value "frmbtsform", change this and be sure to test!

```
jQuery("#save").click(function(ev){
    ev.preventDefault();
    jQuery("#frmbtsform").submit();
});
```

Comment: Hi Jake Rocheleau, i think your answer is same with Sergi Ramón's answer. it work. but the next question is the modal form dont close after submit. even it redirect to frmbts.php.

Comment: It seems you could alternatively add a second button through the jQuery dialog() method.. [this great post](http://www.jensbits.com/2009/08/10/modal-confirmation-dialog-on-form-submit-javascript-jquery-ui-and-thickbox-varieties/) outlines the code nicely. I would copy it here but there's limited room...

just search for the section "jQuery UI" and her code is a few paragraphs down. you should see where I'm getting at. other than this, just try moving the .dialog("close") elsewhere in the operation.

Comment: sorry for my confusing. actually i want to say the modal form do close after submit but the index.php redirect to frmbts.php that i dont want to.